Vector skin is not working on mediawiki page
I am running mediaiwiki on windows server and using IIS
I am getting this error, i have updated my wiki from 1.26 to latest version 1.42.1 , i did not jump from 1.26 to 1.42.1 directly , made few hops !
the page is loading but the vector skin is not applying and in the developer console I see the 500 error
Refused to execute script from 'http://xxxxxx:8080/load.php?lang=en&modules=startup&only=scripts&raw=1&skin=vector' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
and when i click on that link i see this error
[0bd1c37609b216989be1c6fb] /load.php?lang=en&modules=startup&only=scripts&raw=1&skin=vector Error: Class "ResourceLoaderFileModule" not found
I am really frustrated its been 2 weeks i tried everything , downloaded the latest stable skin folder and placed it in skins folder.
Please someone help me out , I am new to this
Tried everything that's on the internet but no luck

Make sure that the skin is on the same branch as MediaWiki. The class ResourceLoaderFileModule was removed in MediaWiki 1.39; therefore, if the skin still requires it, it is older.
This is the general principle: skins and extensions developed by WikiMedia or bundled with MediaWiki ought to have the same version.
You may also need to run composer update within skins/vector directory.

I have downloaded the latest stable version of skin from this link and extracted it in skins folder but still i am getting the same error !!
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:SkinDistributor/Vector  ( 1.42-stable version)
I even run the composer update within the skins/vector directory and when the command is run i am seeing this line in the beginning ..???
Composer could not detect the root package (mediawiki/vector-skin) version, defaulting to '1.0.0'. See https://getcomposer.org/root-version
Do i need to change anything in the composer.json file
@alexander-mashin

Ignore the message by Composer. Have you got wfLoadSkin('vector') in LocalSettings.php? What is the value of requires.MediaWiki in skins/vector/skin.json?

"requires": {
"MediaWiki": ">= 1.42.0"
},
@AlexanderM

It has to do with an extension you have active in your LocalSettings.php file.
Go to /your-mediawiki-dir/extensions and run ag ResourceLoaderFileModule and for each extension that has something like class Base extends \ResourceLoaderFileModule you will need to update with class Base extends \MediaWiki\ResourceLoader\FileModule.
This is due to a breaking change in Mediawiki 1.42. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.42
"ResourceLoaderFilePath – use MediaWiki\ResourceLoader\FilePath"

The problem was with the extensions , although the error was realted to the skin , by replacing the extension files with the latest one the error was resolved !!!
Thanks @w8ody and @Alexander Mashin
